# Overviewmap change ol.OVERVIEWMAP_MAX_RATIO in production

Tags: javascript, oop, openlayers-3

I want that my overview map does not change the zoom level during manipulating main map.
I found the switch in ol-debug.js and can change it:

`ol.OVERVIEWMAP_MAX_RATIO = 0.75;  // global access from console`

But in production `ol.js` this constant has been minified and isn't available at all. I could not set it or override.

How can I overcome it?

Do you know another way how to freeze the zoom level of overview map?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done on the map constructor:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: document.getElementById('map'),
    view: view,
    renderer: 'canvas',
    interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({
        doubleClickZoom: false,
        keyboard: false,
        dragPan: true,
        mouseWheelZoom: true
    }),
    controls: ol.control.defaults({
        attribution: false,
        zoom: false
    }),
    layers: [layers]
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my question was how to freeze the zoom level on the overViewMap, not on the main map. Any ideas?

Comment: Oh I see, no, no idea.